# Why parallelizing this code yields almost no performance improvement on six core machine?

Tags: performance, haskell, parallel-processing

I am learning parallel programming in Haskell using Simon Marlow's book. In the chapter about parallelizing Sudoku solvers, I decided to write my own solver using backtracking algorithm. The problem is that there is almost no performance gain when I try to distribute 6 cases among 6 cores. When I try to do examples with more cases, I get more significant performance gains yet still far from theoretical maximum which should be between 5 and 6. I understand that some cases may run far slower, but the threadscope diagram shows no excuse for such little gain.
Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong. Maybe there is something about ST threads which I am not understanding?

Here is the code:

Sudoku.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

module Sudoku (getSudokus, solve) where

import Data.Vector(Vector, (!), generate, thaw, freeze)
import Data.List ( nub )
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
import Text.Trifecta
import Control.Monad ( replicateM, when )
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.DeepSeq (NFData)
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

data Cell = Given Int
        | Filled Int
        | Empty
        deriving (Generic, NFData)

newtype Sudoku = Sudoku (Vector Cell)
    deriving (Generic, NFData)

instance Show Cell where
    show Empty = "   "
    show (Filled x) = " " ++ show x ++ " " 
    show (Given x) = "[" ++ show x ++ "]"

instance Show Sudoku where
    show (Sudoku vc) = "\n" ++
                    "+ -  -  - + -  -  - + -  -  - +" ++ "\n" ++
                    "|" ++ i 0 ++ i 1 ++ i 2 ++ "|" ++ i 3 ++ i 4 ++ i 5 ++ "|" ++ i 6 ++ i 7 ++ i 8 ++ "|" ++ "\n" ++
                    "|" ++ i 9 ++ i 10 ++ i 11 ++ "|" ++ i 12 ++ i 13 ++ i 14 ++ "|" ++ i 15 ++ i 16 ++ i 17 ++ "|" ++ "\n" ++
                    "|" ++ i 18 ++ i 19 ++ i 20 ++ "|" ++ i 21 ++ i 22 ++ i 23 ++ "|" ++ i 24 ++ i 25 ++ i 26 ++ "|" ++ "\n" ++
                    "+ -  -  - + -  -  - + -  -  - +" ++ "\n" ++
                    "|" ++ i 27 ++ i 28 ++ i 29 ++ "|" ++ i 30 ++ i 31 ++ i 32 ++ "|" ++ i 33 ++ i 34 ++ i 35 ++ "|" ++ "\n" ++
                    "|" ++ i 36 ++ i 37 ++ i 38 ++ "|" ++ i 39 ++ i 40 ++ i 41 ++ "|" ++ i 42 ++ i 43 ++ i 44 ++ "|" ++ "\n" ++
                    "|" ++ i 45 ++ i 46 ++ i 47 ++ "|" ++ i 48 ++ i 49 ++ i 50 ++ "|" ++ i 51 ++ i 52 ++ i 53 ++ "|" ++ "\n" ++
                    "+ -  -  - + -  -  - + -  -  - +" ++ "\n" ++
                    "|" ++ i 54 ++ i 55 ++ i 56 ++ "|" ++ i 57 ++ i 58 ++ i 59 ++ "|" ++ i 60 ++ i 61 ++ i 62 ++ "|" ++ "\n" ++
                    "|" ++ i 63 ++ i 64 ++ i 65 ++ "|" ++ i 66 ++ i 67 ++ i 68 ++ "|" ++ i 69 ++ i 70 ++ i 71 ++ "|" ++ "\n" ++
                    "|" ++ i 72 ++ i 73 ++ i 74 ++ "|" ++ i 75 ++ i 76 ++ i 77 ++ "|" ++ i 78 ++ i 79 ++ i 80 ++ "|" ++ "\n" ++
                    "+ -  -  - + -  -  - + -  -  - +" ++ "\n"
                    where i x = show (vc ! x)

parseSudoku :: Parser Sudoku
parseSudoku = do
            lst <- replicateM 81 field
            (newline *> return ()) <|> eof
            return $ Sudoku $ generate 81 (lst !!)
        where field = (char '.' >> return Empty) <|> (Given . read . return <$> digit)

getSudokus :: String -> Maybe [Sudoku]
getSudokus raw = case parseString (some parseSudoku) mempty raw of
                    Success ss -> Just ss
                    Failure _ -> Nothing

data Direction = Back | Forward

solve :: Sudoku -> Maybe Sudoku
solve sudoku@(Sudoku puzzle) =  if isValid sudoku then
                                Just $ runST $ do
                                    puzzle' <- thaw puzzle
                                    go puzzle' 0 Forward
                                    Sudoku <$> freeze puzzle'
                                else Nothing
                                where go _ 81 _ = return ()
                                    go vector position direction = do
                                        cell <- MV.read vector position
                                        case (cell, direction) of
                                            (Empty, Back) -> error "Calling back Empty cell, this should not ever occur"
                                            (Empty, Forward) -> MV.write vector position (Filled 1) >> go vector position Forward
                                            (Given _, Back) -> go vector (position-1) Back
                                            (Given _, Forward) -> go vector (position+1) Forward
                                            (Filled 10, Back) -> MV.write vector position Empty >> go vector (position-1) Back
                                            (Filled 10, Forward) -> go vector position Back
                                            (Filled x, Forward) -> do
                                                let (r, c, s) = calculatePositions position
                                                row <- getRowMV r vector
                                                col <- getColumnMV c vector
                                                sqr <- getSquareMV s vector
                                                if isUnique row && isUnique col && isUnique sqr
                                                    then go vector (position+1) Forward
                                                    else MV.write vector position (Filled (x+1)) >> go vector position Forward
                                            (Filled x, Back) -> MV.write vector position (Filled (x+1)) >> go vector position Forward 
                                    

calculatePositions :: Int -> (Int, Int, Int)
calculatePositions i = let (row, col) = divMod i 9
                        sqr = (row `div` 3)*3 + (col `div` 3)
                        in (row, col, sqr)


isValid :: Sudoku -> Bool
isValid sudoku = go 0
            where go 9 = True
                go i = isUnique (getRow i sudoku) && isUnique (getColumn i sudoku) && isUnique (getSquare i sudoku) && go (i+1)

getRow :: Int -> Sudoku -> [Cell]
getRow l (Sudoku vector) = go 0
            where go 9 = []
                go c = vector ! (l*9 + c) : go (c+1)

getRowMV :: MV.PrimMonad m => Int -> MV.MVector (MV.PrimState m) Cell -> m [Cell]
getRowMV l mv = go 0
            where go 9 = return []
                go c = do
                    n <- MV.read mv (l*9 + c)
                    rl <- go (c+1)
                    return (n:rl)

getColumn :: Int -> Sudoku -> [Cell]
getColumn c (Sudoku vector) = go 0
            where go 9 = []
                go i = vector ! (c + i*9) : go (i+1)

getColumnMV :: MV.PrimMonad m => Int -> MV.MVector (MV.PrimState m) Cell -> m [Cell]
getColumnMV c mv = go 0
            where go 9 = return []
                go i = do
                    n <- MV.read mv (c + i*9)
                    rl <- go (i+1)
                    return (n:rl)

getSquare :: Int -> Sudoku -> [Cell]
getSquare q (Sudoku vector) = let (y, x) = quotRem q 3
                                start = x*3 + y*3*9
                            in [ vector ! start, vector ! (start + 1), vector ! (start + 2)
                                , vector ! (start + 9), vector ! (start + 10), vector ! (start + 11)
                                , vector ! (start + 18), vector ! (start + 19), vector ! (start + 20)]

getSquareMV :: MV.PrimMonad m => Int -> MV.MVector (MV.PrimState m) a -> m [a]
getSquareMV q mv = let (y, x) = quotRem q 3
                    start = x*3 + y*3*9
                    in do
                        a1 <- MV.read mv start
                        a2 <- MV.read mv (start +  1)
                        a3 <- MV.read mv (start +  2)
                        b1 <- MV.read mv (start +  9)
                        b2 <- MV.read mv (start + 10)
                        b3 <- MV.read mv (start + 11)
                        c1 <- MV.read mv (start + 18)
                        c2 <- MV.read mv (start + 19)
                        c3 <- MV.read mv (start + 20)
                        return [a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3]



isUnique :: [Cell] -> Bool
isUnique xs =  let sv = strip xs
                in length sv == length (nub sv)
            where strip (Empty:xs) = strip xs
                strip ((Given x):xs) = x : strip xs
                strip ((Filled x):xs) = x : strip xs
                strip [] = []
```

Main.hs

```
module Main where

import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.Monad
import Control.DeepSeq ( force )
import Sudoku
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    filename <- head <$> getArgs
    contents <- readFile filename
    case getSudokus contents of
        Just sudokus -> print $ runEval $ do
            start <- forM sudokus (rpar . force . solve)
            forM start rseq
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Error during parsing"
```

I am compiling it with following flags:

> ghc-options: -O2 -rtsopts -threaded -eventlog

Execution with following flags:

> cabal exec sudoku -- sudoku17.6.txt +RTS -N1 -s -l

Gives following performance report and threadscope diagram:

> 950,178,477,200 bytes allocated in the heap
>
> 181,465,696 bytes copied during GC
>
> 121,832 bytes maximum residency (7 sample(s))
>
> 30,144 bytes maximum slop
>
> 7 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
>
> Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
>
> Gen  0     227776 colls,     0 par    1.454s   1.633s     0.0000s    0.0011s
>
> Gen  1         7 colls,     0 par    0.001s   0.001s     0.0001s    0.0002s
>
> TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)
>
> SPARKS: 6 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 6 fizzled)
>
> INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
>
> MUT     time  220.452s  (220.037s elapsed)
>
> GC      time    1.455s  (  1.634s elapsed)
>
> EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.008s elapsed)
>
> **Total   time  221.908s  (221.681s elapsed)**
>
> Alloc rate    4,310,140,685 bytes per MUT second
>
> Productivity  99.3% of total user, 99.3% of total elapsed

[image: Threadscope diagram non parallelized]

Execution with parallelization:

> cabal exec sudoku -- sudoku17.6.txt +RTS -N6 -s -l

> 950,178,549,616 bytes allocated in the heap
>
> 325,450,104 bytes copied during GC
>
> 142,704 bytes maximum residency (7 sample(s))
>
> 82,088 bytes maximum slop
>
> 32 MiB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
>
> Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
>
> Gen  0     128677 colls, 128677 par   37.697s  30.612s     0.0002s    0.0035s
>
> Gen  1         7 colls,     6 par    0.005s   0.004s     0.0006s    0.0012s
>
> Parallel GC work balance: 11.66% (serial 0%, perfect 100%)
>
> TASKS: 14 (1 bound, 13 peak workers (13 total), using -N6)
>
> SPARKS: 6 (5 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 1 fizzled)
>
> INIT    time    0.010s  (  0.009s elapsed)
>
> MUT     time  355.227s  (184.035s elapsed)
>
> GC      time   37.702s  ( 30.616s elapsed)
>
> EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.007s elapsed)
>
> **Total   time  392.940s  (214.667s elapsed)**
>
> Alloc rate    2,674,847,755 bytes per MUT second
>
> Productivity  90.4% of total user, 85.7% of total elapsed

[image]

Here are the contents of sudoku17.6.txt:

> .......2143.......6........2.15..........637...........68...4.....23........7....
>
> .......241..8.............3...4..5..7.....1......3.......51.6....2....5..3...7...
>
> .......24....1...........8.3.7...1..1..8..5.....2......2.4...6.5...7.3...........
>
> .......23.1..4....5........1.....4.....2...8....8.3.......5.16..4....7....3......
>
> .......21...5...3.4..6.........21...8.......75.....6.....4..8...1..7.....3.......
>
> .......215.3......6...........1.4.6.7.....5.....2........48.3...1..7....2........

Comment: You're basically doing `parMap rdeepseq solve` here, right?

Comment: I am creating spark for each task and adding force to ensure whole process will happen in separate calculation so I think yes.

Comment: Well, try if it has the same behaviour. Also, try using some other expensive calculation instead of those sudoku solvers.

Comment: I am not super familiar with `strategies` but I'd say `forM sudokus (rpar . force . solve)`  will solve the sudoku and then create and spark with the puzzle already solve, so you are actually solving in a single thread. I would go with @leftaroundabout recommendation and do `Just sudokus -> print $ parMap rdeepseq solve sudokus` and see if the threadscope profile improves.

Comment: Tried that. Obtained very similar result as with forM sudokus (rpar . force . solve). Both in time of execution and threadscope graph.

Comment: Well, that makes it clearer what situation we're in. — Guess for the actual problem: does `solve` take very different amounts of time for different inputs? It looks a bit like most of the threads are finished quickly, but one has to keep on working much longer. This will then dominate the total computation time.

Comment: Maybe you could try a different strategy. For example `Just sudokus -> print $ map solve sudokus \`using\` (parListChunk 10 rdeepseq)`, so each thread will solve chunks of 10 puzzles, instead of launching a spark for every element.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, I see this in threadscope. But it is not so far from second most computation-intensive thread that such little difference between execution times would be justifed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my machine with GHC 9.0.2 or 9.4.4. I get 158 sec elapsed with N1 and 93 sec elapsed with N6, which is the expected speedup. Although I did not use the eventlog and I did not enable rtsopts. I'm also using `cabal run` instead of `cabal exec`. But I don't think those things should make a difference.

Comment: @Noughtmare I am wondering how were you able to get the x2 speed up. Maybe it was because you were using `time cabal run`, cause that would also include the building time.

Comment: @lehins no I used `cabal run sudoku -- +RTS -N6 -s`. But I did remove the newlines from the txt file because I thought those were just for getting the lines to display correctly here on stack overflow.

Comment: @Noughtmare That makes sense why you couldn't reproduce the problem. :) You runtimes also match up to what I got when I fixed the parser

Comment: @lehins I'm not convinced that that is actually the problem in the original post for two reasons: (1) the other quote blocks for the runtime statistics output also have interspersed newlines that should not really be there, and (2) the threadscope diagram does show the pattern of parallelism that you would expect.

Comment: @Noughtmare I did provide the explanation in my answer about why parallelizing those 6 puzzles does not give a great performance improvement. I also added now some  benchmarks which empirically support my explanation.

Comment: @superstate I highly recommend adding `criterion` as another tool for debugging performance issues in Haskell. Here is an example of how I did it to answer your question: https://github.com/lehins/public/blob/master/haskell/stackoverflow/why-parallelizing-this-code-yeilds-almost-no-performance-improvement-on-six-core/bench/Bench.hs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe it or not, but your problem potentially had nothing to do with parallelization. In the future I'd recommend you first look at the input to the function you are trying to parallelized. It turned out you always tried a single puzzle.

**Edit** - @Noughtmare pointed out that according to Threadscope results posted in the question there is some parallelization going on. Which is true and it makes me believe that the file posted in question doesn't exactly match the one used for creating the results. If that's the case, then you can skip to **Parallelization** section for the answer about: "Why parallelizing this code yields almost no performance improvement on six core machine?"

#### Parser

Long story short there is a bug in your parser. If you ask my true opinion,  it is actually a bug in `trifecta` package documentation, because it promises to fully consume the input [`parseString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta-2.1.2/docs/Text-Trifecta-Parser.html#v:parseString):

> Fully parse a String to a Result.

but instead it consumes the first line only and successfully returns the result. However, honestly, I've never used it before, so maybe it is the expected bahavior.

Lets take a look at your parser:

```hs
parseSudoku :: Parser Sudoku
parseSudoku = do
  lst <- replicateM 81 field
  (newline *> return ()) <|> eof
  return $ Sudoku $ generate 81 (lst !!)
  where
    field = (char '.' >> return Empty) <|> (Given . read . return <$> digit)
```

At first glance it looks just fine, until input is closely examined. Every empty line between the lines with data also contain a newline character, but your parser expects one at most:

```
.......2143.......6........2.15..........637...........68...4.....23........7....
<this is also a newline>
.......241..8.............3...4..5..7.....1......3.......51.6....2....5..3...7...
```

So you parser should instead be:

```
  many (newline *> return ()) <|> eof
```

Side note. If it was up to me this is how I would write the parser:

```hs
parseSudoku :: Parser Sudoku
parseSudoku = do
  (Sudoku <$> V.replicateM 81 field) <* ((() <$ many newline) <|> eof)
  where
    field = (Empty <$ char '.') <|> (Given . Data.Char.digitToInt <$> digit)
```

#### Parallelization

When it comes to implementation of parallelization it seems to work fine, but the problem is the work load is really unbalanced. That's why there is only about x2 speed up when using 6 cores. In other words not all puzzles are created equally hard. For that reason solving 6 puzzles using 6 cores in parallel will always get the performance of the longest solution at best. Therefore to gain more from parallelization you either need more puzzles or less CPU cores ;)

**EDIT**: Here are some benchmarks to support my explanation above.

These are the results for solving each individual puzzle:

[image]

And these two are the sequential and parallelized solvers using one core and six cores respectfully.

[image]

As you can see solving the second puzzle with index `1` took the longest time, which on my computer took a little over a 100 seconds. This is also the time it took for the parallelized algorithm to solve all puzzles. Which makes sense, since all other 5 puzzles were solved much quicker and those cores that were freed up had no other work to do.

Also as a sanity check if you sum up the individual times it took for puzzles to be solved it will match up pretty good with the total time it took to solve all of them sequentially.

Comment: OK, But I don't understand why gain is only 7ms. Shouldn't it go down to time of solving hardest puzzle?

Comment: 7ms is not gain when it takes seconds to solve a puzzle, 7ms its just noise. Time does go down to solving the hardest puzzle. Look at the benchmark for `Sudoku/All/Par` and `Sudoku/Individual/1`, both of them take slightly over 100 seconds.